# Adding compiled element to Angular directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1bKd6EXXsteKdvAnutz?p=preview) I have a directive that contains an Angular UI Modal. The directive takes transcluded elements and populates the modal.

This works fine, however when I try to compile new elements and add them to the modal, this doesn't work. For example, I'm trying to add a compiled `div` to the `root` div. The root div is included (transcluded) in the modal, however when the modal is open it doesn't have any children. Any ideas how to make this work?

HTML

```
  <style>
    #root {
      background-color:orange;
      height:20px;
    }
  </style>
  <div the-modal control="modalCtl">
       Some transcluded content in the modal:
      <input type="text" ng-model="input1" />
      <br>
      You should see text in the orange rectangle:
      <div id="root"></div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("ctl", function($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.modalCtl = {};

  $scope.input1 = "abc";

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.modalCtl.openModal();

    // add compiled content
    var root = angular.element('#root');
    var node = angular.element('<div><b>This is the node</b></div>');
    var content = $compile(node)($scope);
    root.append(content);
  };
});


app.directive("theModal", function($uibModal, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {
      control: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

      scope.control = scope.control || {}

      scope.control.openModal = function() {
        scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          scope: scope,
          template: '<div class="content"></div>',
          appendTo: element
        });
        $timeout(function (){
          transclude(scope.$parent, function(clonedContent){
            element.find('.content').append(clonedContent);  
          })
        })
      };

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you try to append the compiled element to `<div id=#root'></div>` the modal is not ready yet, so `angular.element('#root')` will get nothing. What you need to do is switch the order of append and transclude.

Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/T5gpxYlvsxI5IY4zxR3E?p=info